Why does seperated private/protected routes still share the same states?
Here I decoupled the supposed to be private routes and give them their own PrivateWrapper.
//App.jsx
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>

          <Route element={<PrivateWrapper />} >
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          </Route>

          <Route element={<PrivateWrapper />} >
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          </Route>


        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

Here's the PrivateWrapper
//PrivateWrapper.jsx
function PrivateWrapper() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  console.log(count)
  return (
    <>
      <Link to={"/"}>Home</Link>
      <Link to={"/about"}>About</Link>

      <Outlet context={{ count, setCount }} />
    </>
  )
}

export default PrivateWrapper

Here's the Home and About components:
//About.jsx
function About() {
  const { setCount } = useOutletContext()

  return (
    <div>
       <h1>About</h1>
       <button onClick={() => setCount(prev => prev + 1)}>increment</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default About

//Home.jsx
function Home() {
  const { setCount } = useOutletContext()

  return (
    <div>
       <h1>Home</h1>
       <button onClick={() => setCount(prev => prev + 1)}>increment</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home

Issue/behavior of the provided snippets:
When I am on any of those two routes then click on their increment button (let say I'm on home route and the count is now 1 after I clicked ) then navigate to another route (now I'm on
About route) then click its increment button the count will now 2.
Expect:
What I expect is that those two routes should have their own separate states like you know when we call or use normal function/component multiple times we surely expect it to have their own states as a normal behavior. Why does this not happen in our private route wrapper?

Route and Routes are implemented so they erase themselves from the final output. So while you may have written a pretty complex component tree, what react is actually working with once all the components have rendered looks closer to this (assuming the url is on "/"):
return (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <PrivateRoute>
        <Home/>
      </PrivateRoute>
    <BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);

And when you change to "/about", it becomes approximately this:
return (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <PrivateRoute>
        <About/>
      </PrivateRoute>
    <BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);

So when you move from "/" to "/about", react sees that on the first render you returned a <BrowserRouter> with a <PrivateRoute/> as its only child, and on the second render you also returned a <BrowserRouter> with a <PrivateRoute/> as its child. Since the component type has not changed, react keeps the previous one mounted and just updates its props.
If you want to force it to unmount, you will need to add a key to each PrivateWrapper to tell react that these are different elements.
<Route element={<PrivateWrapper key="home"/>}>
// ...
<Route element={<PrivateWrapper key="about"/>}>


you said So when you move from "/" to "/home", did you mean "/" to "/about"? And here ...and on the second render you also returned a... did you mean when you navigate to another route?

did you mean "/" to "/about"? Yes, that was a typo. Updated. did you mean when you navigate to another route? Yes, that paragraph is talking about a scenario where you change the route from "/" to "/about".

Ok btw it solves now the behaviour I wanted by providing the key props, But can't react differentiate the component (like the ) by its contents? cause they have different child component.

React decides whether to mount/unmount based on two things: component type, and key. If those both stay the same, then the component does not unmount, but just rerenders with updated props. Changes to props (including the children prop) do not cause a component to unmount.

can you explain why in the case of putting them into just one <PrivateRoute />  it doens't rerender between switching routes? And how does react know that the returned <PrivateRoute/> came from identical components (let say in react's mind it says: Oh this <PrivateRoute/> that I recieved is came from identical components ), and in the case of just one <PrivateRoute/> (react says: oh this <PrivateRoute/> that I recieved is indeed the only one).  Does react compare (by reference) the currently mounted components and the one requested to be mounted behind the scene before deciding?

can you explain why in the case of putting them into just one <PrivateRoute /> it doens't rerender between switching routes? I'm not sure I understand what the code would look like with only one <PrivateRoute /> , but somehow two routes. Can you edit your question to show what you mean?

And how does react know that the returned <PrivateRoute/> came from identical components  It doesn't. It's just looking at the types of the JSX elements it receives. It doesn't know how it was calculated. It compares the div from one render to the div on the next render, sees that they're the same type, and so it reuses the existing instance. Then it moves to the children, comparing BrowserRouter with BrowserRouter. No change, so it keeps it. Next is PrivateRoute vs PrivateRoute and keeps it. Only when it compares <Home /> with <About />  does it find something to unmount/mount.

I'm not sure I understand what the code would look like with only one  in my provided code on the post just remove this <Route element={<PrivateWrapper />} > <Route path="/about" element={<About />} /> </Route> and move it's child inside another one
